# How to Fire an Event Only Once on WordPress Post Publish?

Tags: php, wordpress

Thanks for any help with this.

I need to know how to hook wp_insert_post (or whatever is similar and better?) without it firing multiple times.  What is the correct way to do this in WordPress?

For example:

In Plugin.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post', 'add_data') );
...
function add_data()
{
    // This line is outputted twice
    terseErrorLog("This code was executed.");
}
```

Comment: that is the correct way, so there must be something else about your code that's triggering 2 saves.

Comment: I don't think that's correct.  From googling and looking in the database it appears a "revision" is getting saved along with the "publish" version.  wp_insert_post seems to fire once for each event, and I don't know how to hook the clicking "publish" - any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function add_data() {
  global $post;
  if ($post - > post_status == "publish") {
    terseErrorLog("This code was executed.");
  }
}
add_action('save_post', 'add_data');
```

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_post_update says that code will never trigger on creation of a new post, and I need the above code to work both on new post creation and post update.  Tried that code on hook for wp_insert_post and the check for "publish" seems to be invalid here (we never succeed).

Comment: try the save_post action

Comment: I've added a code block to check for whether DOING_AUTOSAVE is defined and to output to my logger whether it is.  It is not defined, but the code is still being outputted twice (two entries of "DOING_AUTOSAVE is not defined" every time I create a new post).

Comment: try skipping that and just having the second block to check if the post status is 'publish'